# when an item is delete from dayabase in mongodb how to show deleted item in item without reload

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

when deleted an item form the user interface working in react and mongodb, the item is deleted form mongodb but not showing on the user interface. when reload the page then the item is gone, without reload page how to remove the item from user interface.

Comment: When you delete a document in the database, you get a "Delete Result" object - which can be used as part of the delete request's response. This response data can be used to update the status of the item in the front end ui.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.